# Xcode if statement not working

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

ok I have a press basic application with the following code in newAppViewController.m 
When I run my app, the label i have called myLabel changes the text but the color of the view ALWAYS becomes blue not red. For some reason its always the else case!
Any Ideas?

```
-(IBAction)click:(id)sender{
  NSString *mystr = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[[sender titleLabel] text] ];
  myLabel.text = mystr;

  if(myLabel.text == @"RED")
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    else self.view.backgroundColor  = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare two string with "==" operator. Use the -isEqualToString: method for this.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try with

```
if([myLabel.text isEqualToString:@"RED"])
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare two scalars you have to use the == operator; When you are comparing objects you have to use the -isEqual: method, and when you are comparing strings you have to use the --isEqualToString: method.

Comment: You don't *have* to use `-isEqualToString:` method. The only difference between the two is a type check. Safer to use `-isEqual:`, very marginally faster to use `-isEqualToString:` if you're 100% sure both objects are NSStrings.